# cumulative filtering using DAX ALLEXCEPT and date table

Tags: datatable, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a DAX query with ALLEXCEPT, and I want to adjust the query to be ALLEXCEPT *IF launch week is not blank*.

The two formulas below are not equaling, but I want them to be the same for the first launch week, and then deviate as time goes on.

[image: Display]

```
Avg Rating This Week = IF(SUM(table[Total Reviews]) = 0, BLANK(), SUM(table[Total Stars])/SUM(table[Total Reviews]))

Avg Rating Since Launch = CALCULATE([Avg Rating], ALLEXCEPT(table, table[Product Name], table[Retailer]))
```

So, when I filter by launch week, the average rating filters out properly to that week, and I want the lifetime reviews to start at launch week and . In other words, lifetime reviews are counting everything, including blank launch week inputs. I tried

1. ```
   Avg Rating Since Launch = CALCULATE([Avg Rating], ALLEXCEPT(table, table[Product Name], table[Retailer], DateTable[Launch Week]))
   ```
2. ```
   Avg Rating Since Launch = CALCULATE([Avg Rating], ALLEXCEPT(table, table[Product Name], table[Retailer], table[Launch Week]))
   ```
3. ```
   Avg Rating Since Launch = CALCULATE([Avg Rating], ALLEXCEPT(Fully_Merged_Reviews_and_Questions, Fully_Merged_Reviews_and_Questions[Product Name], Fully_Merged_Reviews_and_Questions[Retailer]), ALLEXCEPT('Table','DateTable'[Launch Week]))
   ```

To make this as easy as possible, I included a sample dataset, the formulas, and the results.

[image: Display]

```
Avg Rating This Week = IF(SUM(table[Total Reviews]) = 0, BLANK(), SUM(table[Total Stars])/SUM(table[Total Reviews]))

Avg Rating Since Launch = CALCULATE([Avg Rating], ALLEXCEPT(table, table[Product Name], table[Retailer]))
```

[image: sampledataset]

Comment: Please recreate sample data for your example especially for your Fact table. Remove all the columns that do not play any role in your question, unless you want to blur it. Please contain examples of the rows that work as expected and the ones that cause the issue. You might also show the expected results and the actual results you get.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin I already have a sample fact table in the question, and my sample measure avg rating (filtered by launch week 1) on the sample shows an average of3.7. However, my lifetime average rating shows as an average of 4.4 . The lifetime average rating should be the same as both the first week of data and the lifetime rating since launch should be the same number, but my data has historical data which is getting counted in the EXCEPTALL.